# Python's unittest `assertCouldNotTest`?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using [Python's unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module to do some testing that some probability density functions that I have implemented integrate to 1. To test this I am using [Scipy's quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) function:

```py
integral, err = integrate.quad(my_pdf, -float('inf'), float('inf'))
self.assertTrue(isclose(integral, 1))
```

where `isclose` is from [Python's math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose). For some PDFs it happens that `err` is > 1 and `integral` is "very far from 1" such as I would consider this a fail. However this is not a fail of `my_pdf` but a fail of the testing method. To avoid flagging  this as a fail I can do

```
if err > 1:
    continue
```

but in this case I completely skipping this case without any clue that it happened.

Is it possible to somehow flag this kind of failure within `unittest`? Somthing like

```py
if err > 1:
    self.couldNotTest()
```

such that in the end unittest will tell me the number of tests that could not be performed?

Comment: `skipTest` seems reasonable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest However, this seem funky over all. If pdfs with integrals very far from 1 are unsupported, and that's expected, then why are you attempting to test them, in the first place?

Comment: For those PDFs where integration should lead to an error larger than 1 and an integral not close to 1, why not assert _that_ rather than asserting something you don't actually expect then deciding you can't test it?

Comment: Is the code that creates the PDF  *supposed to be able to* create PDFs that cause this problem? Is it supposed to be *possible to know, based on the input*, whether that will happen?

Comment: So, to clarify: I expect that all PDFs that I have integrate to 1. If they don't, that is bad. The thing is that there are some combinations of parameters that are tricky and `quad` cannot handle the resulting function very well. Imagine integrating a Dirac Delta with `quad`, it will probably fail (hopefully `err` will tell you this), but not because your implementation of the Dirac Delta is wrong but because your testing method is not appropriate. So this would be a *could not test* case.

Comment: @Alexander `skipTest` is what I was looking for, thanks. You can post it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound sketchy overall (If pdfs with integrals very far from 1 are unsupported, and that's expected, then why are you attempting to test them, in the first place?)

In any case, I think you're looking for [`TestCase.skipTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest)

Comment: PDFs with integrals far from 1 are unsoported and **not expected**. The thing is that my testing method (`scipy.integrate.quad`) cannot properly integrate some of my PDFs, which does not mean that the PDF does not integrate to 1, it means that it could not be tested.

Comment: "cannot properly integrate some of my PDFs" So why are you using those as input data? Filter them out.

Comment: Because those are important to me, but I have not found yet a function in Python that can integrate those. If you are producing race cars and the pilot that is supposed to test them at high speed is afraid of high speeds and only tests your cars up to 100 km/h, you don't want to remove higher speeds from your testing. You want to raise some kind of warning that your pilot could not test the car at 200 km/h, but until you find a better pilot that is the best you can do.

Comment: @user171780 that makes sense. Good analogy